# How do I prove that a boolean function constructed using $\vee$ and $\wedge$ (without using $\thicksim$ ) must attain the value 1 at least once?

Tags: education

I made an attempt and got this solution. 
To prove this, lets construct a boolean expression using $\wedge$
 and $\vee$
 . In the boolean expression $(p\wedge q)\vee(p\vee q)$
 , by entering the values $p=0$
  and $q=0$
 , we get $f(0,0)=1$
 . Thus we have proved that a boolean function constructed using $\wedge$ and $\vee$
 attains the value 1
  atleast once.
Is this correct?
if wrong then how else do I prove it?

Comment: How is $(0\wedge 0)\vee(0\vee 0) = 1$?

Comment: you need to prove that given any boolean function of that form, it must attain the value 1. So, firstly, you can't choose the boolean function. Secondly, you need to review your understanding of the material, since when you plug in $0$'s you certainly don't get $1$. Enjoy working on your homework!